# Is this too much strain on a PEX joint?

Tags: plumbing, pex

I have some PEX with Sharkbite connectors routed around a joist.  There is some tension where the PEX joins the copper plumbing.  Is it too much?

[image]

[image]

Comment: FYI, that's a stud, not a joist. You could notch into the stud an inch or so to relieve some of the strain. This will not cause a structural problem.

Comment: Ah right.  The 2x6 already has a 2" hole through the center for the plumbing air vent, plus I shaved it down 3/4" to make room for the shower base... so even though it's not load bearing, I was worried about removing too much material.  Ended up sistering to the right and left of the center 2x6 with some 2x4s for my peace of mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I say that the installation is well within the capabilities of shark-bite fittings.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that these junctions do not look like they are under too much stress. I have only once had one of these connectors fail, and it did so within 24 hours of installation. However, if I were concerned about leaks, I'd replace that elbow and those tees with PEX connectors - more secure and much cheaper.